# How cant i show jframe or jdialog with string class name in java swing

Tags: java, swing

How can I show `JFrame` or `JDialog` with `String` class name in Java Wwing

Example : I have a `JFrame` name `com.tan.ui.NewJFrame` in `String` and I want to show this frame

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to get a `Class` reference...

```
Class frameClass = Class.forName("com.tan.ui.NewJFrame");
```

Next, you create a new instance of the class...

```
JFrame frame = (JFrame)frameClass.newInstance();
```

This assumes that the class has a default constructor.  If it doesn't the process becomes significantly more convoluted.

All of these will throw a variety of `Exceptions`, which you are expected to catch.  This also assumes that the class you are trying to load is accessible to the current class loader, if it's not, the process becomes even more convoluted...

Comment: Thank you so much MadProgrammer, Your suggest is so useful.